# Fundamental group of bouquet of 2 circles not in common point

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory

I tried to calculate a fundamental group of bouquet of 2 circles not in common point. Let call this point a (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9xLs.jpg)). It is different from fundamental group in b or I did some mistake? (Fundamental group in b is: $\left<A,B|\emptyset \right>$, my result of fundamental group in a: $\left<A,B,C|BA=AC\right>$)

Comment: Your new group is isomorphic to the original. The relation $BA=AC$ can be interpreted as defining $C=A^{-1}BA$ in terms of the other two. So you can drop $C$ from the presentation and that relation.

Comment: [Tietze transformations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) might interest you.

Comment: Both fundamental groups should be  isomorphic as the space is path connected.